# What does this number between these 2 staff mean?

Tags: piano, sheet-music

Johan Strauss Jr - The Beautiful Blue Danube

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you listened to several recordings of this, following the music?

Comment: Good tips. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I currently can't check against my copy, but I'm convinced, that it means a single bar rest. The number would increase for multi-bar rests. Since it applies to both voices it is printed in between.

Comment: Ohh I see, Thank you!!

Comment: It might be a bit "overkill" to print the "1"; many editions might not bother; but it does make it more visible. (And, especially the second example, is a classic place for someone who isn't paying attention to get an unscheduled solo!)

Comment: @Ruby Welcome to the site. Glad you found your answer. Just know, the way to say "thank you" is to upvote helpful answers (the upward-pointing triangle to the left of the post) and to "accept" the answer that was most helpful (the check mark to the left of the post). Doing this increases the reputation score of the person/people who answered your question.